# Word under text

Tags: math-mode, text

Im trying to create the following:

[image]

However the different methods I tried didnt work to place the text under the word "Sup".

Thank you

Here is an example of what I got:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `...=\sup\limits_{\Vert\xi\Vert=1} ...`? (The `\limits` directive isn't needed if the expression occurs inside a display-math environment.)

Comment: I tried this however the text appears to be subtext from the right of the word sup and not under it

Comment: @Ben - Did you insert the `\limits` directive?

Comment: Sorry indeed thats what solved it. Thank you.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Use `\sup` to generate "sup" in upright lettering. The `\sup` macro can take a "subscript" argument, whose default position depends on the math mode. In inline-style math mode, the argument is placed to the right of and below "sup"; in display-style math mode, the argument is placed below (and centered) "sup". These default positions can be overridden by inserting `\limits` and `\nolimits` directives, respectively, immediately after `\sup`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
% text-style math, default
$J^*(y_0,t_0)=\sup_{\Vert\xi\Vert=1}(\dots)$

\bigskip
% display-style math, default
$\displaystyle
 J^*(y_0,t_0)=\sup_{\Vert\xi\Vert=1}(\dots)$

\medskip
% text-style math, override default with \limits
$J^*(y_0,t_0)=\sup\limits_{\Vert\xi\Vert=1}(\dots)$

\medskip
% display-style math, override default with \nolimits
$\displaystyle
 J^*(y_0,t_0)=\sup\nolimits_{\Vert\xi\Vert=1}(\dots)$
\end{document}
```